# Integrating a new admin-template to an existent aspnetcore project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, angular, yeoman

I am new to angular2, and the process of setting up .net projects and angular2 is quite complicated for me. So, I want to integrate the [CoreUI Angular2_Dev admin template](https://github.com/mrholek/CoreUI-Free-Bootstrap-Admin-Template/tree/master/Angular2_Dev) to an empty [generator-aspnetcore-angular2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnetcore-angular2). Which is the process to integrate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested I have implemented the integration, the code is available in my [repo](https://github.com/FacundoGFlores/Angular2_ASPCORE).